# Protect action camera lens from water drops

Tags: gopro, glass, water, optical-coating

I use a waterproof action camera (GoPro Hero 8 Black, no housing required) for both over and under water shots. Most shots are taken using a remote so I can't really manage the camera when the shot is taken. The lens cannot be changed.

I often get water drops on the lens. I heard of the following can make the lens repel water:

1. Lick the lens (not always practical)
2. Apply a fine coat of wax
3. Apply a diswasher rinse aid (like Jet-Dry or Finish)
4. Windsheild water repelent (like Rain-X)
5. Lens cleaner made for coated sunglasses

What product could I use (bought or DIY) so that the glass over the lens repels water, without damaging the glass?

Comment: Clarify please, is the camera in a weatherproof/waterproof housing (thus coating a clear cover), or will you be coating the lens itself?

Comment: Important detail indeed! The camera itself is waterproof, I don't use a housing for it.

Comment: I assume the lens is integrated? Is it coated (very likely yes)? I would be very, very, reluctant to apply any of these to a coated lens.

Comment: What's your use case? If you're taking shots of waterfalls, you could cover the camera with something whilst you get set up, then only remove the cover to take the shot.

Comment: It's action shots of people (including myself) windsurfing and kitesurfing, zooming by at some 30+ km/h

Comment: I could be wrong, but I believe that a GoPro lens is permanently housed underneath a plastic cover. The significance is just that you are applying whatever you apply to plastic rather than glass.

Answer (score 1):

If the lens is *uncoated*, the thinnest, and least obscuring, coating would be windshield rain repellent, e.g., Rain-X or GlasShield. That said, *any* coating will reduce sharpness somewhat, though it might not be noticeable at the comparatively low resolution of most action cameras.

However, if the camera is mounted semi-permanently, I'd make a "lens hood" cone out of thin plastic sheet to cover the entire camera, held in place by the tripod screw, perhaps. Determine the angle of view of the lens, and roll the cone accordingly. By making the cone sufficiently long, *most* rain and snow should be stopped.

Make sure the mount is sturdy enough to accommodate the additional wind-load of the hood.

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for is:

**Hydrophobic coating**. There are some denominated superhydrophobic. Where water droplets literally bounce like rubberball.

One problem is that I have not found any product that can be applied directly on a lens by simple mortals. Probably because and hydrophobic coating can be potentially hazardous. I only know industrial-grade products.

What you can have is an external water repelent film. I have one on my DJI camera and you do not notice the difference in image quality.

I believe the camera already has some coatings. That is what gives you the silky smooth touch. So. I am not sure about adding a new product over the lens.

---

Take these two paragraphs with a grain of salt.

On the list you mention, I have seen some videos of rain-x, it looks kind of hydrophobic. I would test it somewhere else.

Be very, very careful with waxes, for example, car wax. Most of them have polishers, which are meant to micro scratch the surface to remove old paint. It would be tempting tho, to try one wax labeled for **new paints only**. Do not rub it on your test glass when is creamy, only apply it, and then remove it with a really smooth cloth.

Comment: Most furniture wax doesn't have silicone in it (making it a favorite for woodworkers looking to keep tools protected). However, I've got to ask, how would you apply it then remove it with a really smooth cloth without rubbing it in some way?

Comment: Do not rub it when is creamy.